# Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: c#, wif

I am using Windows Identity Foundation Framework 3.5.  I have installed this on my dev box and I have everything working.  My problem is the production server.

Is there a way to NOT install the framework on the production server and still have the MVC application work?  Right now I am receiving the error:

Type is not resolved for member `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal,Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`.

This is expected, since the framework is not there and obviously the simple answer is to install the framework, but this is out of my control.

Things I have tried, add the references `Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll`, `Microsoft.IdentityModel.WindowsTokenService.dll`, `Microsoft.IdentityModel.resources.dll`, and `Microsoft.IdentityModel.WIndowsTokenService.resources.dll` directly to the project and set them to copy to the output directory.  This does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you double checked that the references are to the dll's inside your project? When you deploy to the server are the dll's still there in the correct place? What server is this- 2003 / 2008 / 2012? What version of the Framework is on the server?

Comment: Thank your for your response.  

Yes, the references are to the dll's inside of the project.

I have no direct access to the deployment box, so I can not verify that the DLLs are in the correct place once deployed, but I am working to verify that now.  

The Windows version of the server is unknown to me, but I would guess 2008.

Again, this server is a black box to me, so I currently know the framework version.. 

Sadly, I am between a rock and a hard place trying to "fix" the bug, but with zero visibility into the deployment box.

Comment: Basically, the gist of the question I asked, is if there are any other DLLs that I need to include in order to get Windows Identity Framework to "work".

Comment: The WIF files you need (as you probably already know) are at C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation\v3.5. The missing type is inside Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll which you already have.

Comment: Thanks nzpcmad.  I figured out that the issue was else where in the deployment pipeline.  I really thought I was going crazy for a while.

Comment: @user959729 would you care to enlighten the rest of us?

Comment: I second this, @user959729. How did you resolve this? Where there missing DLLs or not?

Answer (score 1):

In the hope that this will help someone else with the same problem, the Windows Identity Foundation is now available as a nuget package, you can install using:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel
```

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel/

Comment: It is last updated August 2012. Is this still an up-to-date package?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the DLLs to the bin directory of the MVC application.